# Pyota: prepare_transfer

Tags: pyota

I am trying to construct a simple transaction:
`prepare_transfer` should get as input `transfers: Iterable[ProposedTransaction]`, and two other optional parameters.

How could one make an Iterable out of a ProposedTransaction object?
Is there somewhere a simple working example of using this basic prepare_transfer function? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prepare_transfer` needs an Iterable because IOTA transfers are **[bundles](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/bundles)**: A collection of input, output and 0-value transactions. An Iterable of `ProposedTransaction`s is for example a `ProposedBundle`.

## Example

```
from iota import Iota, ProposedTransaction, ProposedBundle, Address, Tag, TryteString
api = Iota('http://yournode.net:14265',seed = b'SEED9GOES9HERE')

output = ProposedTransaction(
    # receiving address of the transfer
    address = Address(
        b'ADDRESS9GOES9HERE99999999999999999999999999999999999TESTVALUE9DONTUSEINPRODUCTION'
        ),

    # Amount of Iota you want to send
    value = 1,

    # Optional Tag (27-trytes)
    tag = Tag(b'HELLO9WORLD'),

    # Message (2187-trytes)
    message = TryteString.from_string('Hello world!')
    )

bundle = ProposedBundle()

bundle.add_transaction(output)

prepared_bundle = api.prepare_transfer(bundle)
```

Comment: Using bundle as input to prepare_transfer indeed works, however according to the api (https://pyota.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#prepare-transfer), I would have expected that ProposedTransaction would be ok, too.

Comment: I havent tried it, but just passing a list with ProposedTransactions like this: `api.prepare_transfer([output])` will probably work as well.